# How to account for case weights when generating folds for K-fold cross-validation?

Tags: sampling, cross-validation, validation, weighted-data, weights

I am currently working on a binary classification problem where each point in the dataset is paired with a *case weight.* That is, each point is of the form $(w_i, x_i, y_i)$ where:

- $x_i, y_i$ are the features and outcome of a *person of type $i$;
- $w_i \geq 1$ is the number of people of type $i$ in the generate population.

Here, we only care about accuracy on the general population and are aiming to fit a classifier that attains the lowest *weighted error* $\sum_{i=1}^n{w_i \cdot 1[y_i \neq \hat{y}_i ]}$.

My question is: **How do I handle the case weights when generating folds for $K$-fold CV?**

---

I am currently handling this problem as follows: I create an 'expanded' dataset that includes $w_i$ copies of each point in the original dataset $(x_i, y_i)$, then generate folds using the expanded dataset.

The issue with this approach is that, for points with large case weights, we are likely to include copies of the point $(x_i, y_i)$ in the training set and the testing set.

As an example, say I my dataset contains a point $(w_i, x_i, y_i)$ where $w_i = 1000$ (which is very large). If I generate folds for 5-CV using an *expanded* dataset, then I could end up with 800 copies of $(x_i, y_i)$ in the training set, and the 200 copies of $(x_i, y_i)$ in the test set.

Since both the training set and the testing set include the same kinds of points, the training error will end up being very similar to the testing error. As a result, the test error doesn't really reflect out-of-sample performance.

Comment: Are the weights included in the classification scheme itself, as with a weighted regression, or only in the accuracy assessment?

Comment: @EdM I'm not exactly sure about what you mean when you say "included in the classification scheme itself, as with a weighted regression." Could you elaborate / pass me a link? I just need to understand what the difference is before I can provide an answer.

Comment: A [weighted regression](http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmd/section1/pmd143.htm) places different importance (weights) on different cases in setting up the model. For example, if some data points have greater reliability, the model-building process might penalize errors in predicting them more heavily than errors in less-reliably-measured cases. In your case, the $w_i$ would then be incorporated directly into your classification scheme. Alternatively, your classification scheme itself might ignore the $w_i$, and only use them for evaluating the quality of the scheme thereafter.

Comment: Also, could you please clarify whether the weights are determined from your data sample or are based on prior knowledge? Your question suggests the latter, but I would like to be sure.

Comment: @EdM Got it! Yes it's exactly like weighted regression. The weights are determined from prior knowledge. They are incorporated into the classification scheme and used to train the model (so that the model is trained to minimize the weighted error). I edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: One might interpret your question to mean that you have only one record for each "district _type_" of person. Is that the case? How many distinct types of persons are there, how many records?

Comment: I've provided a provisional answer now, as I might not have time to get back to this for a few days. Please clarify how the individual data records correspond to "types of persons" and how sure you are that all individuals of a certain "type" have the same $(x,y)$ pairs.

Answer (score 1):

Model validation estimates how well the model-building *process* provides reliable predictions for other samples from the population. To apply that principle, you need to go through the entire, identical process for each CV fold as you used for the full data set.

If you have a set of records that represents a random sample from an underlying population, each record with its associated weight, then there is no reason to consider the weights in constructing the folds. In 10-fold CV, you conduct the same model building process on 90% of cases, with their weights, and evaluate performance on the held-out 10%, with their weights.

They way you describe the situation, however, it seems that there may already have been some data aggregation, with each individual record representing a subpopulation of known size in the underlying population ("types of persons"), with a single $(x,y)$ pair for each subpopulation, and its weight representing its size. In that case something based on your "expanded data set" or "split weights" might seem to make sense.

With such aggregated data, however, such a CV approach would ignore any differences in $(x,y)$ values among members of an individual subpopulation, which would seem to be a major source of variance that is not taken into account in your model. It's not at all clear that CV on an expanded data set would adequately test your model-building process unless you know for a fact that all members of each subpopulation have identical $(x,y)$ pairs (in which case this approach seems at first thought to be OK) or you incorporate a reasonable estimate of variability into the expanded data set. But if your original model-building process didn't incorporate within-subpopulation variability, then you aren't validating the model-building approach that you actually used.

If there are differences in $(x,y)$ pairs among individuals that are the same "type of person," your model-building process needs to take that into account.